# Laplacian matrix of a graph with negative weights

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

I am trying to calculate the Laplacian and Adjacency matrix of a graphs for positive and negative weights. If a graph be simple with only non-negative weight it is easier. But in my graph I have some negative weights and loops.

Please give me some references and hints if available.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate"?

Comment: @FelixGoldberg I want to write down the Laplacian matrix for a graph with positive and negative weights in an explicit manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most natural definition of Laplacian matrix is to me $\mathcal L=\mathcal I\mathcal I^T$, where $\mathcal I$ is the incidence matrix of an arbitrary orientation of the graph; or more generally $\mathcal L=\mathcal I\mathcal M\mathcal I^T$, where $\mathcal M$ is the diagonal matrix whose entries are the edge weights. Now, the very same definition can be used to define a Laplacian matrix with general (i.e., also negative) weights.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Reference?

Comment: It is working for graphs without loops but there are some obstacle it you add loop in the graph.

Comment: Concerning your first question: What do you mean by "references"? It is a definition. But a standard one, if you mean this: Take a look in Biggs' book, Godsil-Royle's book, Mohar's surveys, etc.

Yes, loops are generally very problematic when it comes to defining Laplacians, even if no weights are assigned.

Comment: How much work has been done to find out the Laplacian for a graph with loop?

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not understand your question yet. The Laplacian is just a matrix defined in a certain way, and its introduction goes back to Kirchhoff. At a certain point in the history (around 1970) people started noticing this matrix was tightly connected with the "usual" Laplacian on domains. If you are interested in some historical remarks, you can take a look at the notes at the end of Chapter 2 of this monograph:

https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.010/mugnolo/springer.pdf

Comment: Thank you for sharing this monograph with me. Yesterday I was just asking about recent research work related to Laplacian matrix of a graph with loop.